# Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 114, so returning the closest version found: 112

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, selenium-chromedriver, aws-amplify, amazon-linux-2

I am running testcases in selenium, installed dependencies i.e. java, maven, google-chrome.
When running command mvn clean test , an error occurs while executing the test case and ends up in build failure.

Error :

Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 114, so returning the closest version found: 112
Failures: ERROR]   jenkins_demo>BaseClass.LaunchingMethod:25 » SessionNotCreated Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.